# Dynamically setting a absolute DIV with a Dynamic Height?

Tags: html, css

Please see the following: http://jsfiddle.net/GWJMf/

What I'm trying to do is have the TITLE fixed, not scroll. But the content scrollable.

Problem is, having a fixed title, makes it very hard to deal with the dynamic range of a title, which can have anywhere from 5 - 250 characters.

Is there a way to have the TITLE be fixed, not scroll, but have the height set based on the title length?

Is this possible w CSS? Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to dynamically set the height based on its content here? 

What is it about the default behavior, where the size is exactly as big as it needs to be, that you are dissatisfied with?

Comment: How can the height be dynamic. WHILE the TITLE DIV is fixed on scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you have all that extra styling. You don't need to style the h2 or any wrapping elements to have it expand based on the length of the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/xd7a4/

I'm not sure of the height you're desiring for the scrolling container however here I set it to 200px.

```
<h2>title</h2>
<div class="scroll">content</div>
```

```
H2 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.scroll {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help :

```
<style>
.content {
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:100px;
width:300px;
height:auto;
}
.title {
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:auto;
background:red;
color:#fff;
}
.text {
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:200px;
max-height:200px;
overflow:auto;
}

</style>

<div class="content">
<div class="title">title<br/>title...</div>
<div class="text">text text <br/> text text...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: chek it now, i think it is what you need. ( change css as you need )

Comment: Thanks but the title scrolls the goal is for it to be fixed.